# Openerp 7 access right layout

Tags: openerp-7

i have created security access for the user's. after creating i got the view like below image.

[image: Access rights Layout]

By giving permissions in .csv file like 1, 1, 1, 1 as shown in below image.

[image: XML FILE]

My Question is this permissions should be bring to front end. the admin can give access rights/permissions to the different users. Can we bring that permissions to front end?

Admin will directly file access like this.

And can we change the layout like below image.

[image: Layout]

How can i do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will be easily Solved using Creating the Controller in ODOO 8.0

**You must have to Follow the Below steps for creating your layout As you want.**

1. Create the new model class (in the form of object) in your module.
   the class contain the login of get the detail of  **ir.model.access**    (which is base object of odoo)
2. Create the View file For displaying the your layout in the form of web page
   the view file use the bootstrap classes for designing your web page layout.
   the view file use as the rendering the detail of  **ir.model.access**  object 
   hear the Layout is based on Qweb Template as well as the web page menu for displaying your data in your webpage
3. Finally run the controller in your browser and see the detail of your access rights in the form of webpage

Comment: in OpenERP 7.0 doen't have any kind of website  interface to rendering the data through out of it. If you want that and do that in OpenERP 7.0 is working but is not the proper way to do that